# Javascript - Improve the sorting on collection of Objects

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am getting an array of objects. For the sake of explanation I have reduced the properties, and left only relevant ones.
I need to sort those objects, and make a new array.
The original array is ofcourse is unsorted.

Objects coming in an array, can have any number of children. Also children can have their own children. But at the end they are all children of the main object (parent_id: null).
   //Unsorted

```
let data = [
{
 id: 1,
 name:'ParentAlpha',
 parent_id: null 
},
{
 id: 2,
 name:'ParentBeta',
 parent_id: null 
},
{
id: 100,
name:'ChildOneAlpha',
parent_id: 1 
},
{
id: 101,
name:'ChildTwoAlpha',
parent_id: 1 
},
{
id: 102,
name:'SubChildOneAlpha',
parent_id: 100 
},
{
id: 103,
name:'SubChildTwoAlpha',
parent_id: 100 
},
{
id: 200,
name:'ChildOneBeta',
parent_id: 2 
},
{
id: 201,
name:'ChildTwoBeta',
parent_id: 2 
}]
```

What I want to achieve is this (same structure, but I have ommited JSON structure).

```
[{ParentAlpha...},
{ChildOneAlpha...},
{SubChildOneAlpha...},
{SubChildTwoAlpha...},
{ChildTwoAlpha...},
{ParentBeta...},
{ChildOneBeta...},
{ChildTwoBeta...}]
```

I have made a working [code](https://jsfiddle.net/evbc0r9s/), but I think it can be made a bit better, and I want to learn more. However I look at the code, I cant figure how to improve it. If someone could point some guides, I would appreciate.

My Working Code:

```
let processedProducts = [],
    processedid = [],
    rearangedProducts = [];

        let subParentProducts = data.slice();
        let masterParentProducts = data.filter((product)=>{
            return product.parent_id === null
        });
        masterParentProducts.forEach((productParent)=>{
          if(processedid.indexOf(productParent.id) === -1){
              processedid.push(productParent.id);
              processedProducts.push(productParent);
          }
                  data.forEach((product, index)=>{
                      if (product.parent_id === productParent.id){
                          processedProducts.push(product);
                          subParentProducts[index] = null;
                      }
                      if (product.id === productParent.id) {
                          subParentProducts[index] = null
                      }
                  })
        });

        subParentProducts = subParentProducts.filter(function(n){ return n !== null });
        processedProducts.forEach((prod)=>{
            rearangedProducts.push(prod);
            let res = subParentProducts.filter((o)=> {
                return o.parent_id === prod.id;
            });
            if (res.length > 0){
                rearangedProducts.push(res[0]);
            }
        });
 console.log(rearangedProducts)
```

Comment: Please include your effort _in the question itself_ as a [mcve]. Links rot.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create function using recursion to build new sorted array.

```js
let data = [{"id":1,"name":"ParentAlpha","parent_id":null},{"id":2,"name":"ParentBeta","parent_id":null},{"id":100,"name":"ChildOneAlpha","parent_id":1},{"id":101,"name":"ChildTwoAlpha","parent_id":1},{"id":102,"name":"SubChildOneAlpha","parent_id":100},{"id":103,"name":"SubChildTwoAlpha","parent_id":100},{"id":200,"name":"ChildOneBeta","parent_id":2},{"id":201,"name":"ChildTwoBeta","parent_id":2}]

function sortArray(data, parent) {
  return data.reduce(function(r, e) {
    if (e.parent_id == parent) {
      r.push(e)
      var children = sortArray(data, e.id)
      if (children.length) r = r.concat(children)
    }
    return r;
  }, [])
}

console.log(sortArray(data, null))
```